# Is ~/.yarnrc used by modern Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I use [modern Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/migration/overview) (v2 or later) as opposed to ["classic Yarn"](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs) (v1.x) in numerous projects. These projects include a *.yarnrc.yml* file that is used by modern Yarn.

I previously had a number of classic Yarn projects, and I have a *~/.yarnrc* file in my home directory from this time. I version control my **rc* files and would like to remove this file if it is no longer needed.

I want to know whether the *~/.yarnrc* file, used by yarn v1.x, is still used by modern Yarn?

Additionally, it would be good to know whether there is any information in *~/.yarnrc* that cannot (or shouldn't) be stored in a project-specific *{PROJECT_ROOT}/.yarnrc* file.